# Unable to download PostgreSQL - Unknown error while running C:

Tags: postgresql

I'm attempting to install `PostgreSQL (10.1)` and pgAdmin 4 for an online course I'm taking. Every time I try to run the .exe file for the download I get the following error message:

> There has been an error. Unknown error while running C:
>   \Temp\postgresql_installer_a8b04b6e60\getlocales.exe

I've tried to Run as Admin, I've tried downloaded previous versions of PostgreSQL and nothing seems to work. I've found others who have had the same issue but haven't found a resolution.

Does anyone know how I can install? Thanks.

Comment: What Version of Windows are you using?

Comment: Windows 7 Enterprise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before installation, I closed all antivirus and antispy-patch for cryptolocker. Some rules added by protection softwares, blocked install file from running another place and change-read settings. First I installed pgadmin 4 v1.6, then upgrade it to v2.0.

I also using PHPStorm built-in database browser. Faster than pgadmin4.